# Score decline with imblearn pipeline and SMOTE

Tags: gridsearchcv, imblearn, smote

I have a pipeline:

```
np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('smote', SMOTE()),
    ('under',RandomUnderSampler()),
    ('cl', KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0))
])

param_grid_pipeline = {
    'smote__sampling_strategy':[.3],
    'smote__random_state':[42],
    'under__sampling_strategy':['auto'],
    'under__random_state':[42],   
    'cl__batch_size':[128],
    'cl__epochs':[20],
}

cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=40, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipeline, param_grid=param_grid_pipeline, cv=cv, scoring='f1', verbose=1, n_jobs=-1)
grid_result = grid.fit(X,y)
print("best_score_",grid_result.best_score_)
```

And the best_score_ is 0.9981313067607172

However, if I exclude the re-sampling from the pipeline and perform it externally:

```
np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)

over = SMOTE(sampling_strategy=0.3,random_state=42)
under = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy='auto',random_state=42)
X,y = over.fit_resample(X,y)
X,y = under.fit_resample(X,y)

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('cl', KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0))
])

param_grid_pipeline = {
    'cl__batch_size':[128],
    'cl__epochs':[20],
}

cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=40, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipeline, param_grid=param_grid_pipeline, cv=cv, scoring='f1', verbose=1, n_jobs=-1)
grid_result = grid.fit(X,y)
print("best_score_",grid_result.best_score_)
```

And I’m getting (out of many runs) considerably better result: 0.9999888503305302

What’s the difference in using re-sampling externally out of pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you perform the over- and undersampling externally, you perform it on the whole data set and only then split it for crossvalidation (which explains the higher score, as with this there is "information" about your training set in the test set)! 
If you include it in the pipeline, you only resample the training set (which is actually the proper way to do it). 
Try doing the shuffle-splits for cross-validation manually and then perfrom the resampling only on the training sets and then calculate the scores manually as well (since you don't actually have a parameter grid in this example this is not much work) and then you should get the same result.

Comment: I was driven by [Marco's blog](https://www.marcoaltini.com/blog/dealing-with-imbalanced-data-undersampling-oversampling-and-proper-cross-validation) and I find your explanation as supportive. Thank you